# Why do I have enter all my logins on every app on a new Android phone?

Tags: google-backup, oxygenos

I've just got a new OnePlus 6. It's installed my apps from my old phone but every one is asking for my login.I have loads and remembering the logins will take ages.

On websites Chrome remembers this, does it not in apps? It doesn't stores all this stuff in the cloud as part of backup?

Comment: Chrome "remembers" your credentials because you specifically allowed it and it's a feature of that app. Android is not Chrome, and part of it's security is that credentials like this are NOT stored in backups that are done by Android. If your applications can use your Google credentials (or other accounts stored as accounts on the device, not individual credentials) than you can enter the information once and allow the application to access those stored credentials. I would suggest that you look at some type of universal password manager, such as Enpass or Lastpass or something similar.

Comment: Google passwords isn't a chrome feature... It just seems so backward apps can't access saved passwords (iOS) supports it now we move from websites to apps.

Comment: Anyway my question is to be certain this isn't supported, done way I didn't realise... Seems it's a feature of Android right?